# I try to run my java spring boot application for the first time and it does not work

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring-boot, xampp

When I try to run the application it sends me this error.

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.189 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ap.iangenta.IangentaApplicationTests

> contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

this is my aplication properties files

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/dbargpro?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

```
spring.datasource.username=admin
```

```
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

and I have xampp running on the port : **3308**

and this is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ap</groupId>
    <artifactId>iangenta</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>iangenta</name>
    <description>Proyecto para argentina programa, Realicé de nuevo el  backend con versiones anteriores por errores que me daban con SpringBoot 3.0.06 </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: XAMPP does not run on a port! Do you mean you have a mariaDB listening on port 3308?

Comment: Yes, sorry I misspoke.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using some UI tool?

Comment: yes mySQLWorbench

Comment: Does user admin with password admin exist? Default is different (root without password).

Comment: Yes. Now trying to open the connection in MySQL workbench I get this error 'You cannot connect to data server. Access denied for user 'admin@localhost' '.

Comment: So you answered your question yourself. the problem is your username/password combination.

Comment: How can I fix it ? I just tried to add a connection with user : root without password and on port 3308 . I get this error: 'Connection warning : Inconpatible server version or connection protocol detected(10.4.28) MYsql Workbench is developed and tested for mysql server versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0' and I currently have mysql server versions 5.7 and 8.0 installed.